# Стоит ли добавлять временные страницы в sitemap?

Tags: html, seo, sitemap

Подскажите пожалуйста, на сколько эффективна на сегодня карта сайта и как она влияет на ранжирование? А также интересует такой вопрос, предположим есть какие то объявления, которые публикуются например в интервале от месяца до трех, после становятся недоступные навсегда. Вопрос, стоит такие страницы добавлять в sitemap или нет, и если да то какой приоритет выбрать, «0»???